# Display selected row index from a list in another panel using SWING

Tags: java, swing, listselectionlistener

I have a list in which I display elements. I want each time I select an element from the list to display its index inside another JPanel.
The code:

```
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        leftList = new JList(listModel);
        leftList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(leftList);
        listScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Proteins"));
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        rightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());   
        for (String name : allNames) {
            listModel.addElement(name);
        }

        leftList.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                int nameIndex = leftList.getSelectedIndex();
                JLabel msglabel = new JLabel("index = " + nameIndex, JLabel.CENTER);
                rightPanel.add(msglabel);
            }
        });
```

This doesn't display anything in the JPanel

Comment: 1. whats reason for rightPanel.add(msglabel);, isn't about msglabel.setText(), 2. for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JList in local variable

Answer (score 0):

In this code when a element is selected it can be moved to another list by pressing a button check this code it will help you

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class Exp extends JFrame {

private JList rl;
private JList ll;
private JButton b;
private static String[] foods = { "asd", "asd", "dfg", "wer", "tyu" };

public Exp() {
    super("Title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ll = new JList(foods);
    ll.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    ll.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    ll.setFixedCellHeight(15);
    ll.setFixedCellWidth(100);
    add(new JScrollPane(ll));

    b = new JButton("Move -->");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            rl.setListData(ll.getSelectedValues());

        }
    });

    add(b);

    rl = new JList();
    rl.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    rl.setFixedCellHeight(15);
    rl.setFixedCellWidth(100);
    rl.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    add(new JScrollPane(rl));
 }
}
```